# Parameterized upsert command over odbc doesn´t work

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters, odbc

i have a problem with doing parameterized upsert commands over odbc.

Thats the upsert command

```
Dim upsert As New OdbcCommand
upsert.Connection = connection
upsert.CommandText = "
INSERT INTO products_replacement
    (products_model, products_replacement)
VALUES
        (@products_model, @products_replacement)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  products_replacement = @products_replacement;
"
upsert.Parameters.Add("@products_replacement", OdbcType.VarChar)
upsert.Parameters.Add("@products_model", OdbcType.VarChar)



For Each Product In ListOfProducts
upsert.Parameters.Item("@products_replacement").Value = Product.Value
upsert.Parameters.Item("@products_model").Value = Product.Key

upsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
NEXT
```

Error message: "ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.7.30]Column 'products_model' cannot be null"

In the Debugger the values of the parameters are correctly set.

Something like that works

```
upsert.Commandtext = upsert.Commandtext.Replace("@products_replacement", $"'{Product.Value}'").Replace("@products_model", $"'{Product.Key}'")
upsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

ListOfProducts is a Dictionary(Of String, String)
Error handling and other stuff is stripped from my above example code.

Parameterized querys are prefered and i had no problems doing the same with MS SQL...
What am I missing?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a try. Invert the order of the parameters insertion. Add to the Parameters collection first the model parameter and then the replacement one

Comment: The order that the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC doesn't use named parameters

You can give them names in the SQL, but you should then imagine that they all get transformed into `?` and are treated positionally by the driver; the name is meaningless

This means you need to add as many parameters to your VB Command.Parameters collection as your statement contains, even if it means repeating values - you cannot reuse VB parameters them by repeating the name in the SQL. The name is still semi useful in VB for indexing purposes:

```
Dim upsert As New OdbcCommand
upsert.Connection = connection
upsert.CommandText = "
INSERT INTO products_replacement
    (products_model, products_replacement)
VALUES
        (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  products_replacement = ?;
"
upsert.Parameters.Add("@pmod", OdbcType.VarChar)
upsert.Parameters.Add("@prep1", OdbcType.VarChar)
upsert.Parameters.Add("@prep2", OdbcType.VarChar)



For Each Product In ListOfProducts
upsert.Parameters.Item("@pmod").Value = Product.Value
upsert.Parameters.Item("@prep1").Value = Product.Key
upsert.Parameters.Item("@prep2").Value = Product.Key

upsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
NEXT
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains everyting!

Comment: PS you don't have to use the odbc driber for MySQL ; there is a .net native one too

Comment: I know but i had weird problems on different systems with the mysql .net dlls.